# efficient way to write this typescript lambda in ng2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an ng2 component which calls a service to get search metadata. So I have a member variable on the ng2 component named searchMetadata.  The result set looks like this:

```
var searchMetadata = 
{
   Authors = Author[],
   Titles = Title[]  
}
```

The Author object has a fully defined set of attributes which describes an Author like FirstName, LastName, etc.  I'm using a select control which requires a binding dataset with objects like { id:123, text:'John Smith'}. So I need to define an authors member variable on the component and use a lambda to transform searchMetadata.Authors into the expected structure. The following is some hacky code which vaguely shows how this would be done with a C# lambda:

```
this.authors = this.searchMetadata.Select(
    x => new {id:x.Id, text:x.FirstName + ' ' + x.LastName});
```

What would be the proper way to write this type of lambda in ng2?

Answer (score 1):

Try the map operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
this.authors = this.searchMetadata.Authors.map(
        x => ( {id:x.Id, text:x.FirstName + ' ' + x.LastName});
```

The `map` operator allows you to "map" from one type to another type.

The hard part was getting the syntax right because using the {} implied that it was a multi-line lambda ... which wasn't what we were shooting for.

Just putting parentheses around the anonymous type seems to do the trick.